# React router page transitions with react-pose do not seem to do anything

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, react-pose

I have the following App:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Search from './pages/Search';
import About from './pages/About';
import posed, { PoseGroup } from 'react-pose';

const RoutesContainer = posed.div({
    enter: { opacity: 1, delay: 5000 },
    exit: { opacity: 0 }
});

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-content-container">
            <Router>
                    <PoseGroup>
                        <RoutesContainer key={window.location.pathname}>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={Search} key="search"/>
                                <Route exact path="/about" component={About} key="about"/>
                            </Switch>
                        </RoutesContainer>
                    </PoseGroup>
            </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

However when I click to About page or go back, I do not see any page transitions. Anyone know why?

Comment: use strangeQuirks instead of react-pose because react-pose got deprecated.

Comment: sorry use what?

Comment: use npm install framer-motion because npm react-pose got deprecated